# Async function with delay c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, timer

I have webpage with a button. when user pressing on button he get  email with the current time.  i need to send him another message after 60 sec async .. [he can still press the button how many times he wants]

how can i do it ?

Comment: Use javascript's setTimeout function to perform another ajax call.

Comment: is there a way to it on server side

Comment: How you do it depends on whether its critical that the second email is sent. If the server restarted within those 60 seconds would you still want the email to be sent or wouldn't it matter? And would it matter if the email was late - would you rather not send it at all rather than late?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking it up here is the answer

```
// Wait X Sec  and then try to send message
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
t.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timer"]);
t.Elapsed += delegate { /*your function here */};
t.Start();
t.AutoReset = false; // do it once
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the client side, as @Holystream suggested, but that will fail if the user leaves your page in thsoe 60 seconds, let alone close the browser.

If you don't want to create your own queuing mechanism, you can try using the Windows Scheduler. Just create a task that will access a URL in your application that will send that email. It'll work with you don't have a lot of such requests, and if the minute is not absolutely crucial (you can miss it a little, the scheduler isn't designed for such resolutions).

Answer (score 0):

You should store data for schedule in DB with schedule time-stamp.

If user press button multiple times that time you can validate in DB if a scheduled email is already exists for the criteria ignore it.

You need to set Cron Job (Scheduler) service to call you page which will send emails from the data in DB if scheduled time is elapsed.

Based on accuracy you need, you need to set shorter duration for Cron Job to send emails.

If you want to set own scheduler service one good C# library is http://csharp-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers/quartz-net.

Hope this helps.